# intellij IDE cannot track XML files with version control

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

#### I add some xxxxMapper.xml.  IDE show that (picture 1):

The new xml files are yellow .

#### I want to add it to git. But I got that picture 2.

The button “+ Add” is unavailable.

[image]

[image]

The gitignore file are:

`/*
!src
!pom.xml
!.gitignore`

global gitignore  /user/xxx/.gitignore_global

`*~
.DS_Store
.idea/`

#### but the sourceTree can track the files

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are ignored by the built-in ignore mechanism. Check Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files list, make sure files are specified there nether explicitly, nor by a pattern.